# GNUplot: data labels are printed on top of each other when a multiplot is created

Tags: gnuplot

I have created a plot made up of four subplots; each subplot is a bar chart. Above the smaller bars I want to print how many units on the y-scale the bar represents. To do this I use 'set label', which works fine if I create individual files for the subplots, but not if I use multiplot. In this case the labels are successively printed on top of each other (i.e. those of the first subfigure also appear in the second, etc.).

Here is a truncated version of my gnuplot script:

```
set terminal postscript eps size 26cm,16cm  font "Helvetica,18"
set out 'all_Figures.eps'

set multiplot
set multiplot layout 2,2 
set bars fullwidth
set data style boxes
set boxwidth 0.5 
set style fill solid 1.0 border -1
set border 3 front linetype -1 linewidth 1.000
set xtics border in scale 0,0.5 nomirror norotate offset character 0, 0, 0
set ytics border in scale -1,0 nomirror norotate  offset character 0, 0, 0
set nogrid
set datafile separator "," 

# ** First Plot **
set label "36" at first 2, 130 center
set label "86" at first 3, 160 center
set size .4,.3
plot 'allPDB_perc.csv'  using 2:xticlabels(1) notitle

# ** Second Plot ** 
set size .4,.3
set label "10" at first 3, 236 center
set label "3" at first 4, 236 center
plot 'allPDB_num_dom.csv'  using 2:xticlabels(1) notitle

unset multiplot
```

Is someone able to tell me how to clear the previous subfigure's data labels prior to generation of the current labels? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh dear >_<  I simply had to unset the labels after plotting, like so:

```
# ** Plot 1 **
set label ...
plot 'datafile.dat'
unset label

# ** Plot 2 **
set label ...
```